# Javascript/regex: Remove comma only if it is not in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

Would it be possible to replace comma only if it is not in brackets.

e.g.
`filters=fuelType=D,make=[BMW,CITROEN,DACIA],price=(0,100)`
to this:
`filters=fuelType=D&make=[BMW,CITROEN,DACIA]&price=(0,100)`

Comment: it seems your gonna replace them with `&`, you need to reformat your question and add what you got. This isn't an help/me place.

Comment: There are dozens of questions on SO about finding things or not finding things inside brackets. Please search for them. The basic notion is to search for **either** a bracketed expression **or** what you want to replace, then replace only the latter.

Comment: Can you provide some wider context on the real problem you are trying to solve here? How did you end up with that comma-separated string to begin with? There's probably a much easier way to (presumably) construct URL parameters rather than applying a confusing regex to that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex you want: `/,\s*(?=[^)^\]]*(?:\(|\[|$))/g`

Here's the js fiddle replacing your string commas outside `[]` and `()` for `&` using `String.prototype.replace()`:

```
var string = 'filters=fuelType=D,make=[BMW,CITROEN,DACIA],price=(0,100)';
var result = string.replace(/,\s*(?=[^)^\]]*(?:\(|\[|$))/g, '&');
alert(result); // -> `filters=fuelType=D&make=[BMW,CITROEN,DACIA]&price=(0,100)`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tmms2mck/

And here's the regex101 explanation of this regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/hAuEQm/1